# TypeError: this.state.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

**UPDATE** 
Response was an array - but the issue came from the backend (Express/Build folder)

Coming back around to an issue that I came across awhile ago.

In my DEV environment - no issues. Once I deploy (Heroku), I am getting the "this.state.workorders.map is not a function". I also attempted "Object.keys and values" in the event it was being treated as such but just gives me back blank values.

This is what I get back below

[image]

[image]

```
const WorkOrder = props => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.workorder.employee}</td>
    <td>{props.workorder.description}</td>
    <td>{props.workorder.duration}</td>
    <td>{props.workorder.date.substring(0, 10)}</td>
    <td>
      <Link to={"/edit/" + props.workorder._id}>Edit</Link> |{" "}
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          props.deleteWorkOrder(props.workorder._id);
        }}
      >
        Delete
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a
        href="#"
        onClick={() => {
          props.markComplete(props.workorder._id);
        }}
      >
        Completed
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

class WorkOrdersList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      workorders: []
    };
    this.deleteWorkOrder = this.deleteWorkOrder.bind(this);
    this.markComplete = this.markComplete.bind(this);
  }

  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
      .get("/workorders/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ workorders: response.data });
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  deleteWorkOrder(id) {
    axios.delete("/workorders/" + id).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

    this.setState({
      workorders: this.state.workorders.filter(el => el._id !== id)
    });
  }

  markComplete(id) {
    axios
      .patch("/workorders/" + id, { isComplete: "true" })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    this.setState({
      workorders: this.state.workorders.filter(el => el._id !== id)
    });
  }

  workordersList = () => {
    return this.state.workorders.map(currentworkorder => {
        return (
          <WorkOrder
            workorder={currentworkorder}
            deleteWorkOrder={this.deleteWorkOrder}
            markComplete={this.markComplete}
            key={currentworkorder._id}
          />
        );
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="containerMax">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-9">
            <h3>Open Work Orders</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="col-3">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-outline-danger"
              onClick={this.onLogoutClick}
            >
              Logout
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <table className="table">
          <thead className="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Employee</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Duration (minutes)</th>
              <th>Scheduled Date</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
              <th>Completed Job</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.workordersList()}</tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

WorkOrdersList.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser })(WorkOrdersList);
```

Comment: Did you checked if `workorders` have value before `.map()`

Comment: You can't use `this.state.map` because `this.state` is an object. `.map` function is only available in `array`, not `object`.

Comment: try changing `this.state.workorders.map` to `this.state.workorders && this.state.workorders.map`

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula you misread, they're trying `this.state.workorders.map` and `workorders` is an array.

Comment: @Sasha: Sure, because I read the title. Lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: this.state.workorders.map is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910300/typeerror-this-state-workorders-map-is-not-a-function)

Comment: ^ probably doesn't answer question, but duplicate nonetheless

Comment: Whatever the axios request returns and ultimately assigns to `this.state.workorders`, it's not an array. My guess is that requesting `/workorders/` in the deployed app fails because you didn't also deploy your express server. To get your React app on heroku, you need to 1. build it 2. move the built files into your express project's public folder 3. deploy the express app

Comment: @ChrisG So in the end... it came down to the express server.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your function `componentDidMount()` if response.data is an Array:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
      .get("/workorders/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ workorders: response.data });  <============ HERE
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
};
```

Then, validate your `componentDidMount()` function:

```
workordersList = () => {

    if (this.state.workorders && this.state.workorders.length) {
        return this.state.workorders.map(currentworkorder => {
            return (
                <WorkOrder
                    workorder={currentworkorder}
                    deleteWorkOrder={this.deleteWorkOrder}
                    markComplete={this.markComplete}
                    key={currentworkorder._id}
                />
            );
    });

    } else { return []; }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try binding `workordersList` in the `WorkOrdersList` component constructor.
It will look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    workorders: []
  };
  this.deleteWorkOrder = this.deleteWorkOrder.bind(this);
  this.markComplete = this.markComplete.bind(this);

  this.workordersList = this.workordersList.bind(this);
}
```

Also you need to wait until axios in `componentDidMount` method completely loads all the workorders.

So in your `render`, in tbody tag you can put the following:

```
{this.state.workorders.length > 0 ? this.workordersList() : ""}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That's not it. a) OP would've gotten an error about `this.state` being `null` and b) OP is already binding the function using `workorders = () => { ... }`